# Getting RSA private key from prime1, modulus and publicExponent

Tags: cryptography, rsa

I am doing a hacking challenge but I don't manage to know how to decrypt the private key from the public key and the given private key "prime1" parameter.

I've seen a private key is composed of :

- modulus
- publicExponent
- privateExponent
- prime1
- prime2
- exponent1
- exponent2
- coefficient

I've been able to retrieve :

- modulus
- prime1
- publicExponent

Concerning prime2, I tried to compute it (by dividing modulus and prime1) and I get the following value :

```
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
```

which translates in :

```
00:19:D2:80:95:CF:46:7F:E6:6A:DB:DB:BA:57:6B:
9C:4C:B1:4F:35:21:96:A4:64:AC:4E:50:1D:F3:D3:
94:9A:EA:60:92:BE:46:05:5C:0E:5E:1A:45:B4:05:
3D:FD:00:C8:7B:1D:26:E0:93:75:FC:AD:B2:32:04:
CB:51:EB:B0:ED:01:07:67:BE:04:EE:8A:C6:E1:91:
25:24:A9:49:1B:BC:B6:74:EF:CF:F3:67:ED:FA:CC:
7D:80:C3:4B:B4:31:FA:36:B5:D1:E2:40:D6:DA:E9:
94:12:C0:62:94:AD:23:E2:54:60:24:5E:DE:E0:63:
AF:51:D9:53:F6:7D:1A:03:30:B4:9C:F3:DE:1F:77:
CE:D7:D8:68:B4:3B:CD:3F:F4:72:6E:6A:55:5E:3C:
39:9F:1B:C1:70:BC:41:60:CC:E1:CF:D7:ED:13:94:
CD:B2:74:FC:5A:30:F8:16:42:A5:23:39:20:A0:03:
2A:B1:8A:36:0A:9C:57:8A:0E:3A:AA:98:23:A0:38:
2D:E7:03:65:4F:3C:81:75:B9:63:E3:04:A7:FF:A2:
A0:31:6C:F0:CF:EB:6A:04:13:17:4A:99:48:E5:30:
9E:EF:6F:3A:BF:E4:3C:BC:C1:86:80:92:96:F8:69:
71:0C:26:3B:AA:4E:C1:F9:59:B0:08:93:AC:3C:23:
06:6B:6
```

Which is quite a problem as it ends with "6".
I added the leading 00.

Values I extracted so far :

```
prime1:
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

modulus:
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

publicExponent:
65537 (0x10001)
```

- Can I get the private key from theses parameters (modulus, publicExponent and prime1) ?
- Is my reasoning about "prime2" right ? (by dividing the modulus and the prime1).
- How to get the last elements ?
- Have you any tool which automatically computes a private key from theses parameters ?

Comment: It seems that your first prime is a multiple of $5$ and of $65119$ and of $980579$

Comment: Does that mean the prime1 is invalid ? @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: The solution is in the sed commands, you didn't replace properly.

Comment: It seems I replaced correctly the prime number hex values with the sed commands (in inverse order of course). I checked several times. But it seems the prime1 is still not prime. Do you assert it is prime ?

Comment: original values may have already be sed substitute result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many reasearches, I've been able to find the correct tool to generate a private key given its modulus (n), prime1 (p) and prime2 (q) parameters (prime2 is even facultative, in reality).

Check out this gist : https://gist.github.com/flavienbwk/54671449419e1576c2708c9a3a711d78.

Tho: there still seem to be a problem with the prime1 number provided as it is... not prime.

Comment: Perhaps this is done on purpose? To my knowledge, RSA would work with non-primes as well. It just would not be secure.

Comment: Thank you @MechMK1, I tested with the non-prime number I've found and it doesn't decode the message we have to decode with the RSA key. Do you know if the leading zeros in "prime1" or "prime2" parameters impact the encoding/decoding ?

Comment: Mathematically speaking, no. Leading zeroes do not affect any computation. `13 + 24 = 37` is the same as `00013 + 00000024 = 0037`. As for the tools used to decode, that again is up to the tool and how it encodes the variables. Though I have to ask, is this for an ongoing challenge?

Comment: Thank you for this precision. Yes it is an ongoing challenge.

Comment: If the challenge is still ongoing, then to my knowledge we only provide very, very limited help, as it would pose as an unfair advantage to you in comparison to others who try to solve it by themselves. Perhaps someone conducting the challenge is willing to give you a hint, if you explain your steps properly?

Comment: Each participant manages to get information. That's part of any challenge! :) I sent an e-mail to the organization doing the challenge, but I don't think they are the kind of company to answer.

Answer (score 4):

This challenge is part of an ongoing French DGSE services challenge. You have one thing that's missing. Check again how you obtained your prime1 number. The parameter went through specific substitutions that can be reversed but not in a simple way.

Comment: @Shutdown I love your pseudo! `ShutUp` wasn't available?